# Saving timestamp with mysqli

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, mysqli, timestamp

I'm having a problem by saving a jQuery UI datepicker date into a TIMESTAMP column via MySQLi.

My variable `$_POST['schedule']` contains `04-09-2015` (dd-mm-yy). I use the following prepared statement:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO campaigns (schedule) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", strtotime($_POST['schedule']));
```

When I check the database, the corresponding timestamp column always resets to `0000-00-00 00:00:00`. If I echo `strtotime($_POST['schedule'])` I get a valid UNIX timestamp.

Also changing the bind_param from `s` to `i` doesn't works.

I feel like I'm doing a trivial mistake but can't understand what it is. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to watch out for the formatting of your date. You are putting in `04-09-2015` which is `dd-mm-yyyy` but what you say the column is reset to is `yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss`

Comment: I tried manually doing strtotime("2015-09-08") in bind_param(). I get the same thing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found to fix this is to use the following and change the format:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $_POST['schedule']);
$date = $date->format('Y-m-d');
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO campaigns (schedule) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $date);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $date = date_create($_POST['schedule']);
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO campaigns (schedule) VALUES (?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

Try this. Change the format.